# How can I understand passing an object and changing it in a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I understand how objects are passed by reference in Javascript. In the following code my function changes a property of an object. It changes in the global scope as expected. I understand it.

```js
let a = {name:'blah1'};

function something(obj1) {
  obj1.name = 'blah2';
  console.log(obj1);  // prints {name:'blah2'}
}

something(a);
console.log(a); // prints {name:'blah2'}
```

In the following code, I rather pass another object to my function and make my first object equal to the second. This time it does not change in global scope. How can I understand this?

```js
let a = {name:'blah1'};
let b = {name:'blah2'};

function something(obj1, obj2) {
  obj1 = obj2;
  console.log(obj1); // prints {name:'blah2'}
}

something(a,b);
console.log(a); // prints {name:'blah1'}
```

Comment: An assignment operation like `obj1 = obj2` breaks any object references, ie `obj1` no longer has any reference to `a` but instead now points to the same reference as `obj2` (`b`). Also, the scope of that assignment is only applicable to your `something` function

Comment: "I understand how objects are passed by reference in Javascript.". IMHO your misunderstanding comes from this statement. Objects are not passed by reference. Reference is passed by value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of `obj1` and `obj2` is limited to the function, `something`. In other words, the scope of the following execution is limited to the function, `something`:

```
obj1 = obj2;
```

Within the function, `obj1` will now reference the same object which `obj2` was referencing and therefore now you can bring a change into that object using `obj1` e.g.

```
let a = {name:'blah1'};
let b = {name:'blah2'};

function something(obj1, obj2) {
  obj1 = obj2;
  console.log(obj1); // prints {name:'blah2'}
  obj1.name='Ravish';
}

something(a,b);
console.log(a); // prints {name:'blah1'}
console.log(b) // prints {name:'Ravish'}
```

but outside the function, these references (i.e. `obj1` and `obj2`) do not exist; that is why `console.log(a)` prints `{name:'blah1'}`.

Answer (score 0):

In the second code sample, you're not making the "first object equal to the second." You're simply overriding the variable `obj1`. That's why `a` hasn't changed when you print it.

EDIT: Just realized Phil beat me to it in his comment. If he ends up posting an answer, accept/upvote his, not mine.